# Selenium in multi-step iframes (paypal)

Tags: selenium, iframe, paypal

I want to test paypal payment with selenium/selenide.

I am waiting for the embedded frame to be loaded, then switch to it, fill out the login form and click the login button.

but how can I wait from there for the next step to be loaded? (there is a significant load-time between the steps that happens after the iframe was initially loaded, so the waitForLoad doesn't catch it)

I have tried `waitForLoad(confirmButton)`, but it timeouts. (I'm still in the iframe focus).

how can I do this?

thanks

Comment: Use locators on the next page and wait for them

Comment: @Gaurav the `confirmButton` IS (only!) on the second page. still waiting for it doesn't work

Comment: can you please show me what did you use for it.

Comment: `@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "confirmButtonTop")
    private SelenideElement confirmButton;`, then `waitForLoad(confirmButton);
        confirmButton.click();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wait command:

```
 public void waitForElementPresent() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("");
    }
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me! (sidenote: the second step was not inside the same iframe after all... that's why the waiting didn't work. BUT this method was/will be nice to have anyway)